# I get “assignment to ‘struct ListNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘ListNode *’”, even though I declared `typedef struct { … } ListNode;`

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am trying to create a Linkedlist using C, and I keep getting this error when I try to compile it,

> warning: assignment to ‘struct ListNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘ListNode *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

These are my structs:

```c
typedef struct {
    void *data;
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
} ListNode;

typedef struct {
    ListNode *head;
    ListNode *tail;
    int size;
} LinkedList;
```

the whole list of warnings is shown down below:

```text
linkedList.c:26:21: warning: assignment to ‘struct ListNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘ListNode *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   26 |         newNd->next = list->head;
      |                     ^
linkedList.c: In function ‘printList’:
linkedList.c:47:16: warning: assignment to ‘ListNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘struct ListNode *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   47 |         currNd = currNd->next;
      |                ^
linkedList.c: In function ‘removeStart’:
linkedList.c:59:16: warning: assignment to ‘ListNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘struct ListNode *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   59 |     list->head = temp->next;
      |                ^
linkedList.c: In function ‘insertLast’:
linkedList.c:88:18: warning: assignment to ‘ListNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘struct ListNode *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   88 |             temp = temp->next;
      |                  ^
linkedList.c:90:20: warning: assignment to ‘struct ListNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘ListNode *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   90 |         temp->next = newNd;
      |                    ^
linkedList.c: In function ‘removeLast’:
linkedList.c:109:14: warning: assignment to ‘ListNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘struct ListNode *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  109 |         curr = curr->next;
      |              ^
```

If any more information is required, I am happy to add more.

Comment: In order for `struct ListNode* next;` to compile the struct requires a tag name (in addition to the typedef): `typedef struct ListNode { ... } ListNode;`. Also we don't see the lines generating your warnings. Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

You created a typedef of an anonymous struct when you defined `ListNode`.  It is therefore not the same as `struct ListNode`. What you need to do is

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    …
} ListNode;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a pointer to your struct as a member of that struct, it needs to have a name *before* the typedef.

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    void* data;
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* prev;
} ListNode;
```

Alternately, start by typedefing:

```
typedef struct ListNode ListNode;

struct ListNode {
    void* data;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode* prev;
};
```

Your struct typedefed to `LinkedList` doesn't require this because it doesn't contain a pointer to a `LinkedList` as a member.

Answer (score 2):

In this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct {
    void* data;
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* prev;
} ListNode;
```

there are introduced two different types: the incomplete structure type `struct ListNode` and  an unnamed (without structure tag name) structure with the typedef name `ListNode`. So the compiler issues errors when you are trying to assign a pointer of one type to a pointer of other type.

To update correctly code you could write for example

```
typedef struct ListNode{
    void* data;
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* prev;
} ListNode;
```

or

```
typedef struct ListNode ListNode;
struct ListNode{
    void* data;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode* prev;
};
```

or

```
struct ListNode{
    void* data;
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* prev;
};

typedef struct ListNode ListNode;
```

Pay attention to that sometimes the term "anonymous structure" is applied incorrectly to unnamed structures (structures without tag names). According to the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 13 An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier
> with no tag is called an anonymous structure; an unnamed member whose
> type specifier is a union specifier with no tag is called an anonymous
> union. The members of an anonymous structure or union are considered
> to be members of the containing structure or union, keeping their
> structure  or union layout. This applies recursively if the containing
> structure or union is also anonymous.

Comment: Of your three examples, is one method preferred?

Comment: @Tyler In my opinion the preferable declaration is struct ListNode{
    void* data;
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* prev;
};

typedef struct ListNode ListNode;

Comment: @Tyler On the other hand, if function declarations do  not require the complete structure type then before the function declarations in a header you can write  for example typedef struct ListNode ListNode; ListNode * create( void ); and so on and then in some translation unit where the functions are defined to provide the complete structure declaration.

Comment: @Tyler No at all. You are welcome.:)